# p:calendar support for locale

Tags: java, primefaces, calendar, locale, french

I am getting some issue when I am trying to add support for locale in JSF primefaces calendar.

I'm passing locale & have also added the locale js file for calendar UI support.
But when user select the date from calendar & after that I have below java code to parse the date & to validate the date.

Current locale : fr
Suppose user select "21-Aoû-2015" from UI calendar.
But for java date format

```
   "21-Aug-2015" in fr locale is "21-août-2015".
```

Similarly :

```
   "10-Apr-2019" is "10-avr.-2019"
```

I'm using below code & selected locale is "fr":

```
    Date date = null;
    boolean isDateValid = false;
    for (String pattern : patterns) {

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, locale);
        try {
            date = df.parse(value);

            String newDateString = df.format(date);
            System.out.println(newDateString);

            isDateValid = true;
            break;

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Date : " + date);
```

So, the main reason, I found is that java DateFormat  parse mis-match. i.e.:
When locale is "fr" french.

Java parse :

For "fr" locale -

Aug => "août" instead of "Aoû"

Apr => "avr." instead of "Avr"

Comment: What is `patterns`? A list? What is the content i.e. which strings?

Comment: patterns are list of selected patterns:
dd-MMM-yyyy, dd-MMM-yy, ddMMyy, ddMMyyyy.. etc

Comment: Well, the order of patterns matters. For example, if you don't want abbreviations but prefer full text width then the patterns with "MMMM" (4 letters) should occur before "MMM" or "MM" in the list.